# Errors when running npm install -g create-react-app in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-20.04

So i'm trying to install react native in ubuntu 20.04, and i'm following this guide https://www.techomoro.com/install-and-setup-a-react-app-on-ubuntu/ , but when running "-g create-react-app" the terminal gives me these problems https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSlIp.jpg , how do i solve them? i have node and npm installed (see the picture)

Answer (score 1):

You npm version is suitable for this:

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

npx command uses create-react-app without downloading it as global.

[If you already added the create-react-app globally, uninstall it first.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start)

Comment: ok, it worked (?), this is the final output https://imgur.com/a/5zJoo9H , what do i do now? I'm really new to this ahah

Comment: It worked. Now you have to call `cd your-app-name` and then `npm start`. But "your-app-name" should be the name of your project.

If it doesn't work, use `cd /home/alex/your-app-name` first.

Comment: yeye i know, i just copied the command you wrote to try if it worked, btw, if you can help me, how do i write a hello world, which file should i edit etc etc

Comment: You can start with editing App.js file. Just add a `<Text>Hello World!</Text>` in a `<View />` component.

Comment: now, this is basically a smartphone app but it opens in the browser, right? I'm probably getting this wrong but k; also, if my guess is right should i open the project in something like android studio?

Comment: React Native App has a web browser support but not stable like Android or iOS one. If your app has usage of for example camera or other platform spesific functions, you should stick with Android or iOS. Web will give error. But if you using a simple layout, you can safely use Web too.

Answer (score 0):

#issue with npm

Try following command,

```
npx install create-react-app -g 
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Sometimes the npm install doesn't work.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a an administrative access issues.
Trying running:

```
    $sudo npx create-react-app my-app
```

It will ask you for the administrators password, fill that in and it should be up and running.